# If these problems are NP-Complete, how are there polynomial time algorithms for solving them?

Tags: algorithm, np, np-complete

I'm studying P, NP, and NP-Complete problems and I've encountered some questions.

I understand that a problem is P if you can solve it in polynomial time, and a problem is NP if it is verifiable in polynomial time. I also understand that a problem is NP-Complete if it is NP and can be reduced from an existing NP-Complete problem.

I know that SAT, 3-SAT, Independent Set, Vertex Cover, Hamiltonian Cycle, Subset Sum, and Traveling Salesman are all NPC. But I encountered a problem where I was told that deciding whether an independent set of 5 vertices exists in a graph is actually polynomial time solvable instead of NPC. This then confused me because I thought independent set problems were NPC.

So then it made me wonder, in what scenarios are these "NPC" problems not NPC and are in fact P? When given a problem, how do I determine whether a problem is P or NPC? What if the problem does have a poly time solvable solution I just wasn't able to come up with it and therefore went down the NPC path. How do I know that I've made a mistake?

Comment: An indepedent set of 5 vertices being polynomial does not seem to make much sense, since if all parameters are bounded, then this is solved in *constant time*. P, NP, etc. says something about the asymptotic behavior. Furthermore it is definitely possible that subsets of certain problems are easier to solve. For example 2-SAT can be solved in polynomial time. So if we use a 3-SAT problem, but where per clause there are only two different terms (like a OR a OR b), then this is in fact 2-SAT.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, I edited my original post. The problem was deciding whether a graph has an independent set of 5 vertices is P or NPC not that an independent set of 5 vertices is NPC.

Comment: The maximal independent set and the travelling salesman problem are NP-Hard and not NP-Complete. They are combinatorial optimisation problems, and you cannot verify their solutions in polynomial time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity

Comment: "What if the problem does have a poly time solvable solution I just wasn't able to come up with it and therefore went down the NPC path." - Don't feel bad, we don't even know whether P = NP = NPC yet.

Answer (score 5):

The problem of finding a maximal independent set of a graph is NP-hard, just like the travelling salesman problem. They are both optimisation problems, and they both involve enumerating a number of cases which is greater than polynomial in the input size.

Given a number `k`, and a graph of `n` vertices, the problem of finding an independent set of `k` vertices is a *separate* problem, for which there is a polynomial-time solution. This is not an optimisation problem.

The solution is bounded by the fact that there are at most `C(n, k)` subsets of five vertices, and for each subset, you need to check at most `C(k, 2)` edges. Each of these is polynomial in `n` for constant `k`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does this mean that all of the problems that I have listed that are NPC are only for the optimization problem of those? And when we ask about a specific situation then it becomes polynomial time solvable?

Comment: The optimisation problems you listed are NP-Hard and not NP-Complete. As Bergi mentioned, certain optimisation problems when parameterised can become simpler. The problem of finding maximal independent sets reduces to a problem of finding an independent set with a parameterised size.

Answer (score 1):

> deciding whether an independent set of 5 vertices exists in a graph is actually polynomial time solvable

Yes, deciding/finding independent sets of **fixed size** (or complementary, finding [cliques of fixed size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Cliques_of_fixed_size)) has a brute-force algorithm that is polynomial-time, usually something like *n<sup>k</sup>* with *k* being the fixed size - in your case *n<sup>5</sup>*.

However, the decision problem that is NP-complete is for **arbitrary** sizes, where *k* belongs to the input of the algorithm. Then it becomes exponential time. The [parameterised complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) field analyses this further.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I'm having some trouble understanding why when it is k then it is NPC but when it's a number substituted for k it is P. If k can be replaced with any number then doesn't that just mean that it can be solved for whatever number k is being replaced with? (not sure if that made sense)

Comment: It's P as long as you actually replace `k` with any fixed number. Just like any algorithm is `O(1)` as long as we restrict the input size with a fixed number. But as soon as we want to analyse the complexity for arbitrarily large `k`s, we get NPC.

Comment: The maximum independent set problem is not NPC. It is NP-Hard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory). Am I missing something? Where is the decision problem that is NP-Complete when `k` is arbitrary?

Comment: @justinpc It's called the "*independent set decision problem*" in that article

Comment: Thanks and my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

There is an analogy that might help you think about it, although it's not the same thing.
There is a mathematical proof that you can't sort arbitrary length array in less than O(n*log(n)). However, if the input is "small" or if you know something about the input, for example, that it contains only k chars, then you can use other methods to solve it quicker, using O(n) algorithms (for example, Redix sort).

When we try to generalize the problem, as we don't have any previous knowledge about the input, things are harder (and sometimes, NP-Complete harder).